# NLP Challenge: Automatically removing bibliography/references?

Tags: nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I recently came across following problem: When applying a topic model on a bunch of parsed PDF files, I discovered that content of the references unfortunately also counts for the model. I.e. words within the references appear in the tokenized list of words.

**Is there any known "best-practice" to solve this problem?**

I thought about a search strategy where the python code automatically removes all content after the last mention of "references" or "bibliography". If I would go by the first, or a random mention of "references" or "bibliography" within the full text, the parser might not capture the true full content.

The input PDF are all from different journals and thus have a different page structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is what makes a bibliography entry distinct from a regular sentence.

Test for the pattern that coincides with whatever (or multiple) reference styles you are trying to remove.

Aka date, unquoted string, string, page numbers in a certain format.

I'd spend some time searching for a tool that already recognizes bibliography before doing this, as it will be unique to each style (MLA etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of additional features to consider for detecting the start of reference setion

- Check if the mention of "references" or "bibliography" is in the last pages as opposed to earlier pages
- Run entity recognition on some length of words (~50?) after the word and if a high number of tokens in the 50 are entities, that indicates journal names, author names, etc.